# What happens algebraically when varieties intersect?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let us take for concrete example the ring $C[x,y]$ and the ideal generated by the element $xy(x+1)$. The varieties consist of three straight lines with intersection points at $(0,0)$ and $(-1,0)$. My question: Is there anything algebraic going on at the intersection points? Do the intersection points reflect anything special about the maximal ideals $(x,y)$ and $(x+1,y)$?

Comment: I think you described the ideal not the way you wanted to. The variety $V(xy(x+1))$ is the union $V(x) \cup V(y) \cup V(x+1)$ of three lines. If you want to intersect, the ideal, which defines the variety, is a sum.

Comment: Actually I do mean the union and I am wondering what can be said about the "pairwise" intersection points of the three lines. The three lines do not intersect at a common point so I am not interested in $(x,y,x+1)$ which would be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are special things going on!

In this case, $X=V(xy(x+1))$ is a union of lines. Then the points where they intersect are precisely the *singular* points of $X$. That is, let $f=xy(x+1)$. Then the points where they intersect are the common zero locus of $\frac{ \partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and $f$.